# Spark in Python Working with Tuples - How can I merge two tuples after joining two RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera, bigdata

I am kinda of new in the Spark Environment and Development.

I have two RDDs in which I merge via a joiner, the result of that joiner is the following:

```
(u'10611', ((u'Laura', u'Mcgee'), (u'66821', u'COMPLETE')))
(u'4026', ((u'Mary', u'Smith'), (u'3237', u'COMPLETE')))
(u'4026', ((u'Mary', u'Smith'), (u'4847', u'CLOSED')))
```

If you see I have two tuples and a key, I want to merge both tuples and leave it as key and one tuple, like the following:

```
(u'10611', (u'Laura', u'Mcgee', u'66821', u'COMPLETE'))
(u'4026', (u'Mary', u'Smith', u'3237', u'COMPLETE'))
(u'4026', (u'Mary', u'Smith', u'4847', u'CLOSED'))
```

Also how can I format this before saveAsTextFile, delimited by Tab. Example

```
10611   Laura   Mcgee   66821   COMPLETE
4026    Mary    Smith   3237    COMPLETE
4026    Mary    Smith   4847    CLOSED
```

I have something like this, but not sure how to access it with the tuple:

```
.map(lambda x: "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" %(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is consistently formatted you can merge your tuples with a simple addition operator...

```
>>> weird = (u'10611', ((u'Laura', u'Mcgee'), (u'66821', u'COMPLETE')))
>>> weirdMerged = (weird[0], (weird[1][0]+weird[1][1]))
>>> weirdMerged
(u'10611', (u'Laura', u'Mcgee', u'66821', u'COMPLETE'))
```

Outputting to text should be simple, but your oddball structure makes it a little odd also. Your lambda isn't bad but you could also do:

```
>>> print('\t'.join((weirdMerged[0],)+weirdMerged[1]))
10611   Laura   Mcgee   66821   COMPLETE
```

I'm not sure that's much better, but it works.

Comment: this one worked: 
`merge=cust_j_orders.map(lambda x: (x[0],(x[1][0]+x[1][1])))`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really familiar with PySpark. I just assumed it was a superset of Python so Python syntax would work.

Comment: yes i used the code you gave me and traduce it to PySpark and worked... :) thanks a lot

Comment: If it worked, I'd appreciate if you up-voted my answer and marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: i tried, but apparently because i am new here, i won't let change the number, cause my reputation is less than 15. sorry about that :(

Comment: this one worked perfectly:
`fmt=cust_j_orders.map(lambda x: '\t'.join((x[0],)+x[1]))`

thanks a lot!!!!! @DennisBaker

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list/tuple comprehension to do it like this example:

```
my_tuple = (u'10611', ((u'Laura', u'Mcgee'), (u'66821', u'COMPLETE')))
new_tuple = (my_tuple[0], tuple(j for k in my_tuple[1] for j in k))
```

Output:

```
print(new_tuple)
>>> ('10611', ('Laura', 'Mcgee', '66821', 'COMPLETE'))
```

Then, to format your output you can do something like this too:

```
print("{0}\t{1}" .format(new_tuple[0], "\t".join(k for k in new_tuple[1])))
```

Output:

```
>>> 10611   Laura    Mcgee   66821   COMPLETE
```

Comment: Welcome. If my answer solve your question you can accept it.

Comment: I couldn't use it, for some reason when I convert it to pyspark, is giving me that the output is '1\t0'
`fmt=cust_j_orders.map(lambda (new_tuple, k): "{0}\t{1}" .format(new_tuple[0], "\t".join(k for k in new_tuple[1])))`

Comment: This "tuple(j for k in my_tuple[1] for j in k)" is likely more versatile than the simple addition I did. But to me, that is PERL levels of confusing. For all it's supposed to be the more elegant, readable language, Python sure has some big warts compared to more modern languages.